# VBA error 1004 on range.value when copying the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am using, but it throws a 1004 error on the `range.value` line.  However it copies successfully the worksheet without formulas (just values). It's just that running this keeps throwing the error 1004.

```
Sub test1()     
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Copy After:=wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbNew.Worksheets(1).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each wks In wbNew.Worksheets
        wks.UsedRange.Value = wks.UsedRange.Value
    Next wks
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of wks.usedrange.value = wks.usedrange.value?
This question is independent of whether the command is permitted by VBA.

Comment: It's already copied with 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Copy After:=wbNew.Worksheets(1).
Your command just copies from and to wks.usedrange. Source and target are the same. Delete this part of the code and the rest should just do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why you trying to do this :

```
For Each wks In wbNew.Worksheets
    wks.UsedRange.Value = wks.UsedRange.Value
Next wks
```

It's like saying that x = x